# flask migration script not recognizing the model which are in different folder (with flask-migrate)

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am coming from Django background. In flask I am looking for the migration command. How should I use the migration-script for this purpose. I referred the document(https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#using-flask-script) for the same.

## My project structure is like.

1. service

   - **init**.py
   - models

     - **init**.py
     - employee.py (contains model declaration)
   - manage.py
   - app.py (start point of project)
   - urls.py (Used blueprint for url routing)

As per the document if I written my models in manage.py file then it will work as expected. But I have models folder where I am writing all the models. So if I hit `python3 manage.py db migrate` command it will not detect any changes from the models file.

- Imported model in **init**.py file of the models.
- imported models in manage.py file.

## Manage.py file.

```
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from flask_script import Manager

from app import app, db

migrate = Migrate(app, db)
manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

Currently it will only create alembic_version table in my database

This is the output

```
>> python3 manage.py db migrate
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.env] No changes in schema detected.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. Default flask-migrate looks model in the same file where we define our migration(In my case it is manage.py file).

Here I created models inside my models package (package name can be any)

To solve this issue we need to perform two steps.
1) Import model in **init**.py file of model package.
2) Import model just after we define

> db = SQLAlchemy(app)

command.
That import statement is unused but it will tell flask-migrate that models are preset in models package.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `flask db migrate` command. If it does not help, try importing your models in manage.py script.

Comment: It is giving me ModuleNotFoundError error. I am more interested in flask migrations script. Thanks for your time and help. :)

Comment: Tried, but no luck. Even most of the documents mention that declare your models in manage.py file which I don't want. I want to create my new models folder.

Comment: @PranayKhilari, what error are you getting? It works once you import models in `manage.py`.

Comment: I am getting ModuleNotFoundError error for importing url in app.py file. It is giving error when I tried to use ```flask db init``` commant, which I dont want to use. I want to use ```python3 manage.py db init``` command. All commands mentioned in document which I am referring is not giving me any error but they are not detecting the models present in model package.